# are there any good statistic visualization libraries for the iphone?

Tags: iphone, statistics

I wonder if every developer would have to code statistic visualization by him/herself, or if there's a lib already that can be used to draw charts, curves, stats, etc. (like in the stock app for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this graphing package, it will also compile on the iPhone:

http://www.mpkju.fr/~graphview/page1/page1.html

Note that I've not used it yet, I ran across it before and made a note of the potential usefulness of it.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the Google Charts API, and just use the images that come back from that:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

For instance, you can retrieve the bytes from this URL

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World

and insert them into an NSImage, or just let the web view do the rendering for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is a cross-platform (Mac / iPhone) plotting framework being developed by a group of scientifically-minded Cocoa developers.  It is based on Core Animation, and was advancing quite quickly the last time I checked in.  You might want to read the [mailing list archives](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss?hl=en) to get an idea of the design goals and current state of the framework.